# Iterating batch values and routing them depending on values contained

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to move an entire batch on a route depending on what values it contains. But as much as I try I'm not able to move the entire batch

I've already tried to split it, but this way objects move one by one, and my DB rollback system is not able to work properly this way so I have to check object values and then move them all together.

```
from(origin())
    .bean(getParser()) //getting batch of objects
    .choice()
    .when(body().method("doesBatchContainErrors").isEqualTo(false))
    .log("Batch doesn't contain errors")
    .bean(saveOnDB())
    .otherwise()
    .to(Channels.ERRORS_AGGREGATOR) //sending for aggregation with previous batches
    .end()
```

```java
private boolean doesBatchContainErrors(ArrayList<CustomItemImporter> batchList){
    for (int i = 0; i < batchList.size(); i++){
        if(batchList.get(i).getState().equals("ERROR")){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't care if I have to use a java method (like the one I wrote down) or a specific camel function, I just need to to check the getState() method inside every object of the batch(which are inside the bean) and if it returns true, then get the entire batch to ERRORS_AGGREGATOR.

Update 26/08/2019

Here's how I solved it.

```java
from(getSaveChannel())
    .bean(getParser()) //getting batch of objects
    .split(body()).stopOnException()
    .choice()
        .when(body().method("getImportState").isEqualTo("ERROR"))
        .to(Channels.ERRORS_AGGREGATOR)
    .end() //end choice
    .end() //end split
    .bean(saveOnDB()) // -> in here i split again and set up an empty return if getImportState is equal to "ERROR"
    .end()
```

It's not moving the entire batch, but it filters errors to the aggregator and filters them again when I save on DB

Comment: Did you tried to use a splitter and agregator with a completionPredicate?

Comment: yes and it worked, but it made my code really ununderstandable. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I think there is a cleaner way to do it. But edit the code please and show us the previous version if possible

Comment: I solved it in another way, I update the post to show it